# Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling! Why?

Tags: gigabit-ethernet

I've always had Gigabit Ethernet in my internal network (workstation, server, switch), but today I stumbled upon such a warning message in the syslog of my OpenSuSE Leap 15.5 workstation:

```ini
[  145.886888] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[  149.670266] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[  171.555271] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[  185.386620] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-700:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
[  185.386635] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control rx/tx
```

This is what the network debug tools tell me:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  uname -a
Linux epica 5.14.21-150500.55.36-default #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Oct 31 08:37:43 UTC 2023 (e7a2e23) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b4:2e:99:c6:e9:9f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    altname enp7s0

╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  sudo ethtool eth0
Settings for eth0:
        Supported ports: [ TP    MII ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: Symmetric Receive-only
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Link partner advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                             100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                             1000baseT/Full
        Link partner advertised pause frame use: Symmetric
        Link partner advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Link partner advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 100Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Auto-negotiation: on
        master-slave cfg: preferred slave
        master-slave status: slave
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 0
        Transceiver: external
        MDI-X: Unknown
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: d
        Link detected: yes
```

The hardware information secition of YaST states the network device as follows:

```
Device: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
```

Following an [advice in the Linux Mint forum](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=390676), I tried to reload the driver in question:

```sh
╭─jacek@epica ~  
╰─➤  sudo modprobe -r r8169 && sudo modprobe r8169
```

But: NO USE! The network interface does start with 1 Gbps speed, but then shifts down to 100 Mbps:

```ini
[ 6470.039948] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[ 6470.341900] libphy: r8169: probed
[ 6470.342189] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: RTL8168g/8111g, b4:2e:99:c6:e9:9f, XID 4c0, IRQ 81
[ 6470.342196] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: jumbo features [frames: 9194 bytes, tx checksumming: ko]
[ 6470.402643] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-700:00: attached PHY driver (mii_bus:phy_addr=r8169-0-700:00, irq=MAC)
[ 6470.603188] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[ 6477.014457] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 6478.210793] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[ 6481.311902] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 1Gbps/Full - flow control rx/tx
[ 6482.077305] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Down
[ 6496.122480] Generic FE-GE Realtek PHY r8169-0-700:00: Downshift occurred from negotiated speed 1Gbps to actual speed 100Mbps, check cabling!
[ 6496.122492] r8169 0000:07:00.0 eth0: Link is Up - 100Mbps/Full (downshifted) - flow control rx/tx
```

The cables, sockets, and patch panel I'm using are all Cat 5E, and the patch cables are ready-for-use stuff. The hardware I'm using has been working flawlessly for several years, so I don't really know why my network is suddenly downshifting.

What's suddenly wrong here? Does this flaw have something to do with a system upgrade from Leap 15.4 to 15.5 I performed a couple of months ago? Or shall I try out another cable?

Comment: “…check cabling!” is in the error message. Perhaps something got knocked out of place? “Or shall I try out another cable?” It can’t hurt.

Comment: Just age can do that. A lot of CAT5e is CCA (copper clad aluminum). Its cheaper than pure copper, but you get what you payed for. After some years (as little as 5-8 years in a very humid environment) cable quality degrades making them unfit for gigabit. CCA generally degrades because of metal-diffusion on the copper-aluminum boundary which changes the electrical properties. The same effect (even with full copper cable) can be seen on the connection points between cable and connector if they are of dissimilar metals. E.g copper against copper-alloy contacts in the (patchpanel) connector.

Comment: First and most likely option is that the cable has degraded or a core has snapped. If a cable is exposed to the elements or pulled tight or has a sharp bend somewhere then time and small temperature shifts can weaken it over time. If the cable is more than a few years old then it might just be the end of it. Try a different cable first.

Answer (score 0):

I plugged the patch cable of my workstation into another RJ45 socket, and everything worked fine at full speed.

The culprit may be the socket, the wall cabling, the patch panel, or the switch (maybe because of the high age of my equipment).